# Not receiving mail through PHP mailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail using php mailer, but for some reason I am not receiving the emails. I have created a php file with the following code. When I am sending mail to gmail, yahoo, hotmail, I am not getting the email. When I send it to icloud.com I am getting the mail all the time. I have checked the junk, spam folders as well but not there either.
The way I am running now is like this
http://mywebsite/sendmail.php
and I am seeing  "Message sent!" on the browser when load the pageing

```
<?php
/**
* This example shows sending a message using PHP's mail() function.
*/
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('someemail@gmail.com', 'Admin'); 

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('someemail@yahoo.com', 'First Last');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'This is the subject';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
//$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Body = 'This is a test';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: are you running localhost?

Comment: If you actually trying to send email from gmail.com, did you login? If yes, show that code too, or else: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail

Comment: What does the message look like before sending it? instead of calling `$mail->send()` call `$mail->preSend();` then output the result to a log file. `file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/mail.log', $mail->MIMEHeader . \PHP_EOL . $mail->MIMEBody, FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. No I an not using localhost. I have a hosting service with hostgtor. I am not sending email from gmail, but to gmail and yahoo accounts. Also, just noticed something. When I am sending the email with the code above, it takes over 4-5 hours before the mail is received to yahoo or gmail. however mails to icloud.com received immediately. Why it takes over 5 hours for message to be delivered to yahoo or gmail emails?